# grails app root context

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a test grails app setup with a context of "/testapp". When I add a link in my gsp that references / it does not go to the root of my grails.app.context, but to the root of my grails.serverURL property.

For example given a link with href "/css/main.css"

I would expect that this link would actually look in localhost:8080/testapp/css/main.css instead of localhost:8080/css/main.css

Is there a way that I can get references to / to start at my grails.app.context vs the grails.serverURL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the question is how do you add your links into your gsps?

We do things like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'stylesheet1.css')}"/>
```

and

```
<g:javascript library="prototype"/>
```

by using the g:javascript and resource tags and methods, you tell grails to set the path for you...

I suspect you are just putting standard tags in...

goto

http://grails.org/doc/latest/

and, under tags in the left hand nav, look for resource and/or javascript to get an idea (its difficult to link directly in to the docs...:()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are using the tag libraries, but we have a situation with an external library that has a hardcoded /path/to/css that we cannot change. Sounds like we will have to find a work around.

Answer (score 22):

use the request contextPath value on the page

```
${request.contextPath}
```

and then prepend the additional host information if necessary to construct the complete url

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue to OP - how to have grails form links that start at the context root and NOT server root?

You can do so using the "uri" attribute for g:link and g:createLink tags. For example:

```
<g:link uri="/login">login</g:link>
```

will prefix any context if applicable, and produce the following

```
<a href="/login">login</a>  if your app is at the http://server/ 
<a href="/testapp/login">login</a> if your app is at http://server/testapp/
```

Not sure why it's an [undocumented](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) attribute in the reference docs, but I found it in the [Javadocs - ApplicationTagLib](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ApplicationTagLib.html#createLink)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using the resource tag into your grails CSS directory, like mentioned above. However, you can also use the `resource` method to find the root context of you web application using the same tag:

```
${resource(uri:'/')}
```

then just use that string wherever.

Answer (score 0):

And when it comes to elements like stylesheets I'd recommend creating a simple tag that'll do the trick, something along those lines:

```
class StylesTagLib {
    static namespace = "g"

    def stylesheet = { args, body ->
        out << """<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: args.href)}"/>"""
    }
}
```

and later on in your code use it like this:

```
<g:stylesheet href="main.css"/>
```

Obviously you can fiddle with the conventions (should I use a predefined folder? should I add the .css extension automatically? stuff like that) but the general idea is to hide the ugliness behind a nicely defined tag.